# Debug specific URL-Route in PhpStorm

Tags: php, debugging, laravel, xdebug, phpstorm

I started a new project with Laravel in PhpStorm (including Xdebug) on my local MAMP server. The entry point for this Laravel is `localhost/project/public/index.php`, which I can easily debug by adding a new PHP Web Application to the Run/Debug Configuration.

But let's say, I'd like to debug a specific route, like `localhost/project/public/users/get/1`. I don't know where to add this route in the debugger. I know how to do this in Eclipse, but can't finde the settings in PhpStorm (but I have to use PhpStorm)

When I try, to input it directly in the 'File' input field, it fails with 'file is not specified or invalid', adding the route to the 'Arguments' field also doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are doing something completely wrong if you see such warning for **PHP Web Application** Run/Debug Configuration -- it accepts URLs and NOT file names, so no validation is performed in this regard as it simply **HAS NO** "File" field. "Arguments" field is only available in **"PHP Script"** type of Run/Debug Configuration which is for running scripts in **console/CLI environment**.

Comment: For debugging web apps I always recommend using Zero-Config approach (when no Run/Debug configuration is required as you control debug session from browser extension/bookmarklet) -- http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

Comment: Thank you, I just followed the instructions in your link and it works like a charm. I'd accept this as an answer.

Comment: Feel free to submit and later accept your own answer (describe your experience and what you were doing wrong in first place, if anything) -- I do not see how I can put my small comment as a complete answer.

Comment: Answered in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68137191/how-to-get-phpstorm-to-ignore-incoming-connection-from-certain-domain-with-xdebu/77571541#77571541