# How to get PhpStorm to ignore incoming connection from certain domain with Xdebug

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

So I've got multiple projects on multiple domains that talk to each other, all mapped to my local IP 127.0.0.1. When debugging one with Xdebug, sometimes an "Incoming Connection" popup appears for one of the other projects I have.

I usually tell it not to listen to those connections as I only want it to listen to the project I'm currently working in, but like an idiot I accidentally accepted one of the connections for a WordPress project I have while debugging a separate Laravel project.

Now everytime I want to debug my Laravel project, at least the part where it connects to the WordPress one, I have to deal with the debugging getting interrupted by WordPress's `wp-cron.php` all the time. I can't for the life of me find a way to tell PhpStorm to not listen to connections from that WordPress project now that I accidentally allowed it once.

Is there any way to do this?

Or for example if I have `domain1.test` and `domain2.test`, is there any way to tell PhpStorm to just listen to `domain1.test` and NOT any other domain (or remove other domains if accepted?)

Comment: 1) `Settings/Preferences | PHP | Servers` -- that's your registered server connections that IDE knows. Delete unwanted. 2) `Settings/Preferences | PHP | Debug` -- enable `Ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations` option. 3) `Settings/Preferences | PHP | Debug | Skipped Paths` -- you can add unwanted entry scripts here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Make sure that your `Settings/Preferences | PHP | Servers` only has the correct domain entry.
2. Enable `Settings/Preferences | PHP | Debug | Ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations`.

Comment: it doesn't help

Comment: @Dr.X Please contact us via Help | Contact Support, we'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to filter URLs to be debugged. This works if your application has a certain entrypoint like most frameworks does. Possibly your index.php file.

When "Break at first line in PHP scripts" is activated in settings debug panel or from "Run" menu.
Your very first line of entrypoint file (index.php) will be welcoming each request that triggered debug session.

This gives us an option to use PHP to filter debug process.

Steps to make it possible ;
1 - Put a breakpoint to that first line manually.
2 - Disable "Break at first line in PHP scripts".
3 - Right click to the breakpoint (red round button)
and select  "Condition" and write your PHP condition.

As an example I am using this to filter requests to some files using this;

`preg_match('[.js|.css|.png|.gif|.ico]',$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) === 0`